# Mobile game without game engine

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I am planning on making a 2D mobile game for iOS and Android. It will have animations (including some simple flash/light and particle effects, like in Candy Crush), but the only physics the game will need is hit-detection between 2 circles, and dragging a sprite across the screen. And the game isn't very complicated. Since these would be easy to implement on my own, I'm considering using the native iOS/Android SDKs for this (on Xamarin), with no game engine.

Is this a good or bad idea? Would avoiding using game engines, and using the native SDKs (on Xamarin) improve the performance of my game? Wouldn't fixing bugs become easier (in some odd cases) since both platforms are separated into different builds/code? Looking at games like Candy Crush, I don't see any physics involved and so believe that a game engine isn't even needed for a game like that. Any advice/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Why does every new game dev want to do things "without an engine"? It's masochism, unless you want to make an engine.

Comment: "[...]  improve the performance of my game?" That's something you'll know when you'll have some experience. If you want to release a game, use an engine. Make it, ship it, sell it, take the money, rinse, repeat. I don't play much games, but lately I've seen someone play a game on an iPad. The game was running at 20 FPS. The guy was _playing the game_. This makes you realize how important the performance is (i.e. not a lot).